# Python pipe cp1252 string from PowerShell to a python (2.7) script

Tags: python, powershell, character-encoding, pipe, cp1252

After a few days of dwelling over stackoverflow and python 2.7 doc, I have come to no conclusion about this.

Basically I'm running a python script on a windows server that must have as input a block of text. This block of text (unfortunately) **has** to be passed by a pipe. Something like:

`PS > [something_that_outputs_text] | python .\my_script.py`

*So the problem is:*

The server uses cp1252 encoding and I really cannot change it due to administrative regulations and whatnot. And when I pipe the text to my python script, when I read it, it comes already with `?` whereas characters like `\xe1` should be.

*What I have done so far:*

Tested with UTF-8. Yep, `chcp 65001` and `$OutputEncoding = [Console]::OutputEncoding` "solve it", as in python gets the text perfectly and then I can decode it to unicode etc. But apparently they don't let me do it on the server /sadface.

A little script to test what the hell is happening:

```
import codecs
import sys

def main(argv=None):
    if argv is None:
        argv = sys.argv
        if len(argv)>1:
            for arg in argv[1:]:
                print arg.decode('cp1252')

    sys.stdin = codecs.getreader('cp1252')(sys.stdin)
    text = sys.stdin.read().strip()
    print text
    return 0

if __name__=="__main__":
    sys.exit(main())
```

Tried it with both the `codecs` wrapping and without it.

*My input & output:*

```
PS > echo "Blá" | python .\testinput.py blé
blé
Bl?
```

--> So there's no problem with the argument (blé) but the piped text (Blá) is no good :(

I even converted the `text` string to hex and, yes, it gets flooded with `3f` (AKA mr `?`), so it's not a problem with the `print`.

[Also: it's my first question here... feel free to ask any more info about what I did]

**EDIT**

I don't know if this is relevant or not, but when I do `sys.stdin.encoding` it yields `None`

Update: So... I have no problems with cmd. Checked `sys.stdin.encoding` while running the program on cmd and everything went fine. I think my head just exploded.

Comment: Just want to add that meanwhile I was fortunately given a Linux server and everything is working out fine with encodings ... No more PowerShell headaches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about saving the data into a file and piping it to Python on a CMD session? Invoke Powershell and Python on CMD. Like so,

```
c:\>powershell -command "c:\genrateDataForPython.ps1 -output c:\data.txt"
c:\>type c:\data.txt | python .\myscript.py
```

**Edit**

Another an idea: convert the data into base64 format in Powershell and decode it in Python. Base64 is simple in Powershell, I guess in Python [it isn't hard either](http://docs.python.org/2/library/base64.html). Like so,

```
# Convert some accent chars to base64
$s  = [Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes("éêèë")
[System.Convert]::ToBase64String($s)
# Output:
w6nDqsOow6s=

# Decode:
$d  = [System.Convert]::FromBase64String("w6nDqsOow6s=")
[Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString($d)
# Output
éêèë
```

Comment: At first I had my program working with files (it was also good for me to track what I was doing). But unfortunately I was told by the admins to not do that (it's a Hospital server...). But yeah, it works perfectly fine on CMD. Even with the simple example `echo "Olá" | python .\myscript.py`. **Why??**

Comment: @orestes, if the admins are worried abot data security, how about writing into an EFS encrypted folder? In such a case the file contents are quite safe from prying eyes. As for the why part, check the [code page](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9822905/503046) on [CMD session](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1259468/503046).

Comment: OK, the second part really helped. Thanks a lot. However, I was given a Linux server to work on now and moved away from the troublesome cp1252 encoding ;-) thanks!