# PHP to Powershell - Escaping

Tags: php, powershell, iis-7, active-directory, escaping

I am trying to make a php script to change Active Directory User passwords by executing powershell. http://pastebin.com/XYvSFjPv - for those that wish to look

Ran into a problem escaping quotes `"` and `'`
My goal is to make full use of all characters (utf08 standard) including quotes
as I've been through many websites of how to escape and still not come to a satisfactory result.
I would like some help in escaping these characters if at all possible because I have found no function to easily escape characters.

I am running this script on a Windows 2008 server with IIS 7, PHP 5.4 and Powershell v1.0

and by observation the command `shell_exec()` sends to command-line which in turn starts up powershell (I am not sure if i have to double escape to make this work.)

And to make sure it's clear I would like to escape the following characters `'` and `"` for Powershell v1.0 using the `shell_exec()` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to pass complex arguments to Powershell is to use the `-EncodedCommand` switch. It takes a Base64 encoded parameter string. No escaping is needed for the quotes or any other weird characters for that matter. This has been [discussed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6296159/503046) in other [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19042901/503046). Php's got a [`base64_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php) function that should work.

Comment: Will this disarm injection attacks as well?

Comment: @Werezwolf *No*, it will not. Base64 will preserve the input. Powershell will get input without worrying about `{`, `"` and the like. Sanity checks and sanititzing input must be done with other techniques.

Comment: I belive this is apart of my answer but not the total. Ive enforced in php utf8 charictors and i am going to continue to manualy escape charictors. For i havent found a function for it. This answer should solve any problems passing it through command line as shell_exce() runs cmd.

Comment: And i aslo apoligise for my english for its not my strong point. XD